# Build Configuration - Build checkbox not checked by default

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've recently noticed that when I add projects to an existing solution, the `Build` checkbox is not checked automatically. Consequently, when I try to run my application, it fails because I forgot to modify the build configuration.

[image: Screenshot of Build configuration - the Build checkbox was unchecked for two projects.]

I'm sure that my projects were automatically building before, and I don't remember changing any settings.

My google-fu has failed to find a solution to this minor, but annoying, issue. Is there a setting to tell Visual Studio to automatically check the `Build` checkbox when I add a project?

Comment: No clue on what is going on, the same thing has been happening to me ever since I started using VS2013.

Comment: At least I'm not the only one - I thought I had changed a setting. Or losing my mind. I guess that's still a possibility though :)

Comment: You might want to [log a bug at MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) regarding this interesting behavior.

Comment: Strange - it seems to have come right again on it's own. I'll keep testing and see if I can reproduce, and log a bug as suggested. Thanks!